# How to declare Map from constructor (key) and class instance (value) in Typescript?

Tags: dictionary, constructor, typescript

Following code has error with component.constructor (Entity constructor and addComponent and removeComponent methods).

Error: Argument of type 'Function' is not assignable to parameter of type 'typeof Component'.

How I can declare Map where is key = Class constructor, value = Class instance?

```
declare class Component {
  constructor(...argArray: any[]);
}

// declare type MapOfComponents = Map<{new(): Component}, Component>
declare type MapOfComponents = Map<typeof Component, Component>

export default class Entity {
  static id = 1;

  id: number;
  components: MapOfComponents = new Map();

  constructor(components?: Array<Object>) {
    this.id = Entity.id++;

    components.forEach((component) => {
      this.components.set(component.constructor, component);
    });
  }

  addComponent(component: Component): this {
    this.components.set(component.constructor, component);
    return this;
  }

  removeComponent(component: Component): this {
    this.components.delete(component.constructor);
    return this;
  }

  hasComponent(ctr: typeof Component): boolean {
    return !!this.components.get(ctr);
  }

  getComponent(ctr: typeof Component): Object {
    return this.components.get(ctr);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A constructor is a function, so you can write:

```
declare type MapOfComponents = Map<Function, Component>
```

Comment: Martin, thank you. It's work. 

I know, it's not necessarily, but doest it possible to declare MapOfComponents that

let entity = new Entity();

function test() {};

function A(a) { this.a }

let a = new A(1);

entity.components.set(test, a);

will generate error (a is not instance of test)?

Comment: If you mean a compile time error, then you can use union types: `declare type MapOfComponents = Map<Function, OneComponent | SecondComponent | ThirdComponent>`  ... but I don't think you'll like it. If you mean runtime error, then you can use `if (!(a instanceof Component)) { /* report error */}`

Comment: Yes, thx!
I have some problems with tsc and tslint.
How to change tslint rule for file?
I need use qoutemark single insted double in one file.
How I can do this like /* tslint qoutemakr: double*/?

Comment: Can you accept the answer then, if it solves your issue?

Comment: and with tsc.
tss doesn't have any warnings or exceptions in lib.core.es6.d.ts, but tsc always has errors with sentences like this:
    [Symbol.toStringTag]: "Symbol";

Comment: It's better to write a new question for your tslint issue.